# How to pass Array to Handlebar helper using nodemailer-express-handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, nodemailer, express-handlebars

I have trouble understanding how to use Handlebar Helpers with nodemailer-express-handlebars.

I want to send out an E-Mail asking customers to review their order. For that, our Shop sends an array with their order to our Webserver.

This is my JS code for the mail:

```
const hbs = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');
const Handlebars = require("handlebars");

const viewPath =  path.resolve(__dirname, './templates/views/');
const partialsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './templates/partials');

function reviewMail(req){

    const lineItems = req.body;
    
    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "HOST",
        port: 587,
        auth: {
        user: "USER",
        pass: "PASS"
        }
    });


    transport.use('compile', hbs({
        viewEngine: {
          extName: '.hbs',
          // partialsDir: viewPath,
          layoutsDir: viewPath,
          defaultLayout: false,
          partialsDir: partialsPath,
        },
        viewPath: viewPath,
        extName: '.hbs',
      }))

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'MAIL',
        to: 'MAIL',
        subject: 'Bitte bewerte deine Bestellung',
        template: 'index',
        context: {
          lineItems: lineItems
        }
    };

    transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    });
};




module.exports = {
    reviewMail
}
```

And the header of my index.hbs file contains:

```
  <script>
        Handlebars.registerHelper("each", function(context, options) {
        var ret = "";
      
        for (var i = 0, j = context.length; i < j; i++) {
          ret = ret + options.fn(context[i]);
        }
        return ret;
      });
</script>
```

The body then includes this (HTML Code shortened):

```
{{#each lineItems}}
<!-- HTML Code -->
<a href="{{lineItemUrl}}"><img class="adapt-img" src="{{lineItemImage}}"
<!-- HTML Code -->
{{/each}}
```

This is an example array, which would be passed:

```
{
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "lineItemName": "neowake® Chroma Watch",
      "lineItemUrl": "https://www.neuro-shop.net/products/neowake-chromawatch"
    },
    {
      "lineItemName": "BIOTONICS Vol.1 - Körperliche Ausleitung",
      "lineItemUrl": "https://www.neuro-shop.net/products/biotonics-vol-1-korperliche-ausleitung"
    },
    {
      "lineItemName": "neowake® Source Code Album (Physische CD)",
      "lineItemUrl": "https://www.neuro-shop.net/products/neowake-source-code-album"
    }
  ]
}
```

I do get an E-Mail but without the {{#each}} - block, probably because I don't pass the data correctly. Where is my mistake?

Comment: What is the value of `req.body` that is being assigned to the local variable `lineItems`?

Comment: This: {
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "lineItemName": "neowake® Chroma Watch",
      "lineItemUrl": "https://www.neuro-shop.net/products/neowake-chromawatch"
    },
    {
      "lineItemName": "BIOTONICS Vol.1 - Körperliche Ausleitung",
      "lineItemUrl": "https://www.neuro-shop.net/products/biotonics-vol-1-korperliche-ausleitung"
    },
    {
      "lineItemName": "neowake® Source Code Album (Physische CD)",
      "lineItemUrl": "https://www.neuro-shop.net/products/neowake-source-code-album"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Then should you not have `const lineItems = req.body.lineItems;`?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, oversaw that.. Thanks!